# AltGr treated as Alt + Ctrl

Tags: javascript, linux, windows, input, keyboard

On windows, I would expect <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key to compose diacritic characters which it does successfully, but looking behind the scenes it turns out that windows <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key is equivalent to <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> as evident from here[1] (Use the tool to interpret keyboard events on this page). This is the behavior only on windows; on linux AltGr is **not** split into <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> like this.

How do I differentiate normal <kbd>AltGr</kbd> operation from <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> operation in such a case on windows ?

[1] http://javascript.info/tutorial/keyboard-events

Answer (score 0):

In [modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=keyboardevent-location), you can use the [`location` property of the keyboard event](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#widl-KeyboardEvent-location) to determine whether the left or the right Alt key (the right being AltGr in your case) is pressed.

```js
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    // For pretty output in the demo
    var locations = {"1": "Left", "2": "Right"};
    var keys = {"17": "Ctrl", "18": "Alt"};

    // Checking e.keyCode and e.location
    document.getElementById("test").value = 
        "Key: " + (keys[e.keyCode] || e.keyCode) + 
        ", Location: " + (locations[e.location] || e.location);

    e.preventDefault();
});
document.getElementById("test").focus();
```

```html
<input id="test" type="text" style="width: 100%;" value="Click here and test alt, ctrl and altgr"/>
```

Comment: Well, it still doesn't fit my use case. Doing a ctrlL + altL +  <some key> would give you location =0. Similarly, doing a AltGr + <somekey> would also give you location = 0. How would i differentiate in such a case ?

Comment: ofcourse i can detect the previous invocation of ctrl or alt and use the location property to check if left or right ctrl/alt was pressed

Comment: This is what I was about to suggest, because I don't think there is a portable way of detecting them as modifier keys. I know there are some things working only in (old?) IE, and other ways will give different results on Linux than on Windows, etc... Actually, in Windows, in most cases it's even expected that you can use Ctrl+Alt+something the same way you could use AltGr+something (this is because back in the days there were keyboards without AltGr), for example I can use Ctrl+Alt+ß to get `\` on my German keyboard here.